# How to get an access token for Microsoft Graph from Python

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, authorization, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am developing a python web application, that is supposed to connect and acquire data from Microsoft Graph. I am facing difficulties acquiring the proper access token.

Here is what my index() function looks like.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():    
    token = auth.get_token_for_user(app_config.SCOPE)

    url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        displayName = response.json().get("displayName", "displayName not found")
    else:
        displayName = "Error fetching displayName"

    print("display name: " + str(displayName))

    # Fetch all task lists
    url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists"
    #headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer Ew....Ag=='}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        
    if response.status_code == 200:
        task_lists = response.json().get("value", [])
        print(str(task_lists))
    else:
        print(response.text)
```

The above code is executed only after ensuring the user is logged in.

When I try to acquire the access token via:

```
    token = auth.get_token_for_user(app_config.SCOPE)
```

And use it to query:

```
    url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    displayName = response.json().get("displayName", "displayName not found")
```

I get the expected results, i.e: my display name is properly returned.

Next, I try to extend my code to query my todo lists:

```
    url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        
    if response.status_code == 200:
        task_lists = response.json().get("value", [])
        print(str(task_lists))
    else:
        print(response.text)
```

I get as a result:

```
    status_code = 401
    {"error":{"code":"UnknownError","message":"","innerError":{"date":"2024-02-08T18:54:34","request-id":"8557b311-....-....-....-............","client-request-id":"8557b311-....-....-....-........"}}}
```

One could argue that my application does not have the proper permissions, but if I:

1. Use Graph explorer to fire the exact same query, and
2. Extract the access toekn from Graph explorer, and
3. embedd it into my code using

   ```
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer Ew....Ag=='}
   ```

My code manages to retrieve the expected data. So this already rules out the possibility that my application does not have the required access writes.

Any idea what is wrong with

```
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']}
```

That it works with

```
    url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
```

And not with

```
    url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists"
```

These are some configs that might be relevant:

```
    CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
    CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")

    AUTHORITY = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{os.getenv('TENANT_ID', 'common')}"

    REDIRECT_PATH = "/getAToken"  # Used for forming an absolute URL to your redirect URI.

    ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'

    SCOPE = ["User.ReadBasic.All", "User.Read", "Tasks.ReadWrite"]
    SESSION_TYPE = "filesystem"
```

I also tried with

```
    SCOPE = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
```

This is how my login is performed in an earlier step

```
    def login():
        return render_template("login.html", version=identity.__version__, 
            **auth.log_in(scopes=app_config.SCOPE,
            redirect_uri=url_for("auth_response", _external=True),          
         ))
```

And here are the permissions configured in my application

[image]